# Copy document to another library using workflow SPD 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library

I need a workflow to be able to copy a PDF file from one library to another using SPD 2010 SP 2010 Enterprise. The trigger will be a user ticking a tick box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **Copy List Item action** to copy a document from one library to another.

I suggest you these useful links:

[SharePoint Designer Workflow: Copy a document from one library to another](https://cypher19.wordpress.com/workflow-copy-document-from-one-library-to-another/)

Comment: Thanks. I actually thought copy list item was just for lists not libraries but I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

@Nk SP has provided the correct references that would help you to copy documents from one library to another including PDF documents. But regarding the last statement that you mentioned in question - "The trigger will be a user ticking a tick box" would not be possible with SharePoint Designer Workflow.

SharePoint Designer Workflow is triggered on 3 events:

1. Manual (Manually running the workflow on item)
2. Item Created
3. Item Modified

Your last statement requirement can be addressed by creating a custom ribbon feature developed in Visual Studio. The custom ribbon feature will be deployed as a ribbon button where user will tick the PDF documents in library and on click of this custom ribbon button the selected PDF will be copied to destination library.

Comment: A tick box being ticked on the current item = 3. Item Modified

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but just in case anyone is looking for a solution. Use SharePoint designer to add a custom action to the *view ribbon*, then set this custom action button to trigger the workflow. This button (you can even create your own icon) will now be in the *file ribbon*, clicking it starts the workflow. I use it all the time, because the start workflow page is cumbersome or confusing to users.