# Is there a managed copy function in modern doc libraries?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sync, libraries

Can I keep 2 copies of the same doc synchronized in two different libraries so that if one gets updated the other does too?

Answer (score 0):

With Sharepoint Designer you could create a workflow that is initiated when an item is modified.  I know that with a 2010 workflow (also compatible with 2013, not sure about SPO) there is a `copy to [document library] command`.  Which would do what you need.

Here is an [existing post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138877/copy-document-to-another-library-using-workflow-spd-2010) which deals with this subject.  Here's [another one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95730/copy-file-in-a-library-to-a-folder-in-another-library-with-workflow?rq=1) for your research.